# Jenkinsfile writing string includes square brackets into file

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my declarative Jenkins file, I'm writing some string into a .ini file that I have in my workspace. When running the pipeline, I'm facing issues with writing that string.

Here's the code from my JenkinsFile:

```
sh "echo -en \n[azcli_servers] >> ./Inventory/hosts.ini"
```

When running the pipeline, I get the error above:

> [azcli_servers]: not found
>   script returned exit code 127

How can I write these special characters "[]" as regular chars and pass that string "[azcli_servers]" into the file?

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to quote your whole string. Example:

```
sh """echo -en "\n\\[azcli_servers\\]" >> ./Inventory/hosts.ini"""
```